# C-shell prompt color

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh, csh

I wan to change the color of my csh shell. I've edited my `.cshrc` file, following the instruction I've found [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Esrhuang/teaching/code_snippets/prompt_color.tcsh.html), and included this in it:

```
set  yellow="%{\033[1;33m%}"
set     end="%{\033[0m%}"

set prompt="${yellow}[`id -nu`@`hostname -s` <csh>]${end}# "
```

However, when I run the `csh` command in my terminal my prompt changes to this:

[image]

I also tested to run the command `tcsh` and for the tcsh the color is changed as I want:

[image]

How can I do that to my csh prompt too? I'm not very familiar with the shell syntax.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063225/how-to-color-a-prompt-on-freebsd-cshrc) , which gives a `csh` version instead of a `tcsh` version. In general, remember, `tcsh` is mostly backwards compatible with `csh`, but `csh` is _not_ forward compatible with `tcsh`.